# how to do I enable the dropDownMenu is Handsontable, even if I set it to true it's not visible

Tags: reactjs, handsontable

```
startCols = {15}
   startRows = {15}
   rowHeaders={false}
   colWidths={150}
   filters={true}
  checkedTemplate={true}
  
   hiddenColumns={{
     
     indicators: true
   }}
   dropdownMenu={true}
```

I tried this:

```
 dropdownMenu={[
        'remove_col',
        '---------',
        'make_read_only',
        '---------',
        'alignment'
      ]}
```

but still it's not visible in handsontable's hotTable?
It's not showing it in the table even if set contextMenu to True.
(I am using react for this).

Comment: It seems that you did not import and register the DropdownMenu module. Here https://handsontable.com/docs/javascript-data-grid/modules/ is how to do that. What framework do you use?

Comment: Maybe you can provide more info like what lib you are using, or simply more code about it which could help a lot